# How to update property and get result having property value in consecutive order in array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, object

I have array of object `list`, parameters `rid` and `rorder` are passed.

-> 1. If `rid` is same as `id` in the list, then update the `itemorder` with `rorder` value.

-> 2.UpdatedList `uList` property `itemorder` if same value exists, then increment the value until its been consecutive order (1,2, 3...n)

```
var rid = 23; var rvalue = 2
const list = [
  { id: 12, itemorder:null, place : 'IN' },
  { id: 24, itemorder: 1, place: 'MY' }, 
  { id: 23, itemorder: 4, place: 'AU' },
  { id: 44, itemorder: 3, place: 'SG' },
  { id: 54, itemorder: 2, place: 'CN' }, 
];

//updated List will be
const uList = [
  { id: 12, itemorder:null, place : 'IN' },
  { id: 24, itemorder: 1, place: 'MY' }, 
  { id: 23, itemorder: 2, place: 'AU' }, // updates since id and rid same // 2
  { id: 44, itemorder: 3, place: 'SG' }, // 4
  { id: 54, itemorder: 2, place: 'CN' }, // 3
];

// uList property itemorder has same value here `2`, increment until consecutive (1,2, 3...n).

Expected Output

[
  { id: 12, itemorder:null, place : 'IN' },
  { id: 24, itemorder: 1, place: 'MY' }, 
  { id: 23, itemorder: 2, place: 'AU' },
  { id: 44, itemorder: 4, place: 'SG' },
  { id: 54, itemorder: 3, place: 'CN' }, 
];
```

```
Tried 

var listChanged = list.map(e=> ({
  ...e,
  itemorder: e.id===rid ? rvalue : e.itemorder
}))

var result = listChanged.map(i => ({
  ...e,
  itemorder: (i.itemorder !== rvalue && i.itemorder > rvalue) ? (i.itemorder || 0)+1 : i.itemorder
}));
```

```
when passing var rid = 23; var rvalue = 1

Expected Output:

[
  { id: 12, itemorder:null, place : 'IN' },
  { id: 24, itemorder: 2, place: 'MY' }, // 1 becomes 2
  { id: 23, itemorder: 1, place: 'AU' }, // updates since both id and rid same
  { id: 44, itemorder: 4, place: 'SG' },//3 becomes 4
  { id: 54, itemorder: 3, place: 'CN' }, //2 becomes 3
]

no repeat values so increment, follows consecutive order (1,2,3..n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rid = 23; var rvalue = 2
const list = [
  { id: 12, itemorder: null, place: 'IN' },
  { id: 24, itemorder: 1, place: 'MY' },
  { id: 23, itemorder: 4, place: 'AU' },
  { id: 44, itemorder: 3, place: 'SG' },
  { id: 54, itemorder: 2, place: 'CN' },
];

let ridIdx = list.findIndex(x => x.id === rid)

orderedList = list.map((l,i) => {
    if(i === ridIdx) {
        return {
        ...l,
        itemorder: rvalue
        }
    }
    if(i > ridIdx) {
        return {
            ...l,
            itemorder: l.itemorder + 1
        }
    }
    return l
})

console.log(orderedList)
```

The above code should work.
So far with what I understand from your question, we do the following steps:

1. Find the item in the `list` with given rid
2. Now map over the `list`, and based on the index found from step 1, return as it is by default, return itemorder to be rvalue if item index matches index above and return by incrementing existing itemorder value by 1 if item index is greater than found index

Comment: thanks for reply, when try with var rid = 23; var rvalue = 1, seems to have `itemorder`value repeated

Comment: You can't rely on indexes I think. It works in current example but would break whenever a lower number is later in the array.

Comment: @Wimanicesir, thanks for reply, yes it failes when i pass var rid = 23; var rvalue = 1, how to resolve this

Comment: @Codelearn could you please post some other scenarios with expected output, so that the question is more clear? For instance, what is your expected output with rid=23 and rvalue=1?

Comment: @MysticCode thanks a lot for reply, have updated the question , Added Expected Output when passing var rid = 23; var rvalue = 1